# Changes are not appearing when replacing the aspx files in IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-6

Changes are not appearing when replacing the new files in IIS. After googling i found that, deleting the files from asp.net temporary folder(path - C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files) IIS would re-compile the entire website and the new changes would appear. However i could not find any files in the above said path. In such cases where can i find the compiled asp.net file?

Comment: What are you replacing?  What changes are you expecting to see?  How are you deploying your web application such that you need to replace individual files at all?

Comment: You probably need to Publish instead of just copying over the ASPX files.  Depends how the project was set up.

Comment: web pages(aspx and its code file), and the website was published with The build -> publish web site command